# Number of entries in SAP R/3 table using Pyrfc

Tags: python, pyrfc, sap-r3

How do you use the [Pyrfc Python library](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC) to query the number of entries in an SAP R/3 database table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of three methods to do this using Pyrfc. Modify the following example with your SAP R/3 server connection settings and desired table name:

```py
from pyrfc import Connection

params = dict(
    ashost="1.1.1.1",
    sysnr="1",
    client="100",
    user="username",
    passwd="password",
)
table = "MKAL"
with Connection(**params) as conn:
    # Method 1
    result = conn.call("RFC_GET_TABLE_ENTRIES", TABLE_NAME=table, MAX_ENTRIES=1)
    entries = result["NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES"]

    # Method 2
    result = conn.call("EM_GET_NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES", IT_TABLES=[{"TABNAME": table}])
    entries = result["IT_TABLES"][0]["TABROWS"]

    # Method 3
    short_field = "MANDT"  # table field with short data length
    result = conn.call(
        "RFC_READ_TABLE",
        QUERY_TABLE=table,
        ROWCOUNT=0,
        FIELDS=short_field,
    )
    entries = len(result)
```